# Manipulating Dom in Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, dom

I'm creating a web in angular 2. I have a Jquery code to add 2 inputs and 1 delete button when a custom button is clicked,so, when the user clicks on delete button, it remove the inputs ( manipulating the DOM ).

Jquery Code:

```
//Adiciona campos extra nos sócios
    var campos_max = 10;   //max de 10 campos
    var x = 1; // campos iniciais

        $('#add_field').click (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();     //prevenir novos clicks
                if (x < campos_max) {
                        $('#listas').append('<div>\
                                <div class="form-group">\
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome sócio:</label>\
         <div class="input-group">\
             <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>\
                <input class="form-control socio" name="nome[]" type="text" placeholder="Nome sócio..." required>\
         </div>\
           </div>\
           <div class="form-group">\
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Participação (%):</label>\
         <div class="input-group">\
             <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>\
                <input class="form-control socio part" name="participacao[]" type="text" placeholder="Participação..." required number="true">\
         </div>\
           </div>\
            <input href="#" type="button" id="add_field" value="Remover campo" class="remover_campo btn btn-warning">\
                                </div>');
                        x++;
                }
        });

        // Remover o div anterior
        $('#listas').on("click",".remover_campo",function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
                x--;
        });
```

How can I do this in Angular 2?
I read about elementRef and Renderer, but I'm so confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Angular you don't inject HTML into your page from JavaScript. (you can, but it's not a good practice)

All the HTML should be in your template, wrapped with *ngIf tags to add and remove the elements when needed.

```
<div *ngIf="isShowing"> your HTML here </div>
```

Then you can bind to a button's (click) event to toggle the boolean 'isShowing' when clicked:

```
<input (click)="isShowing=false">
```

So the final form should look something like this:

```
<div>
  <h2>form</h2>
  <form>
    <div *ngIf="showForm">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <button type="button" (click)="showForm=false">hide form</button>
    </div>
    <button *ngIf="!showForm" type="button" (click)="showForm=true">show form</button>
  </form>
</div>
```